# Conditional statement in SSIS

Tags: ssis, conditional-statements

Is it possible to have a conditional statement in the flat file destination activity?

The condition is that when the SQL Query generates rows (or when the number of rows is greater than 0), then it will export the results to a txt file.

I tried using RowCount and Conditional Split activities after the ADO source activity but it still generates the reports even if there are no rows retrieved.

Below is the screenshot of the data flow activity:

[image]

Comment: Are you loading the result of the row count into a variable? Are you using this variable in your conditional split? Please post the expression you are using. Also debug your code and ensure the variable is being populated as expected.

Comment: This is actually my test solution. The result of the rowcount is stored in @RowCount and I'm using this variable also in the conditional split. However, it still generates the file even if there were no records retrieved.

Comment: Ado net Source what Database you are using? You can't Row count element use with variable in the same dataflow.... row count element works only after dataflow is finished in which he used...

Comment: Check this https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-precedence-constraints-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: As Justin alluded - first get the row count on it's own in one data flow task. Then create another seperate data flow task that creates and loads the flat file, but set is 'Enabled' property to be based off the rowcount. That's my guess, not ever having used rowcount. This is going to be very slow if the source is large. You'd actually be better off running a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table and loading the result into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

As Justin alluded - first get the row count on it's own in one data flow task. Then create another seperate data flow task that creates and loads the flat file, but set is 'Enabled' property to be based off the rowcount (using expressions). That's my guess, not ever having used rowcount

Like this, except your second step uses expressions to enable or disable. http://www.daveturpin.com/2009/10/write-row-count-to-flat-file-using-ssis-part-ii/

Keep in mind this is going to be very slow if the source dataset is large. You'd actually be better off running a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table and loading the result into a variable. That way you are not counting each individual row and needlessly streaming data into SSIS.